# How to make one reusable Vue component in order not to repeat the code?

Tags: vuejs2, devextreme

We use Vue 2.6 and DevExtreme library. The working code looks as following:

```
<div>
    ...
        <template #icon>
            <i
                id="icon1"
                class="dx-icon-refresh icon-cursor"
                @click="getReferralLink"
                readonly
                @mouseenter="toggleDefault1"
                @mouseleave="toggleDefault1"
            />
            <v-dx-tool-tip :visible="defaultVisible1" :hide-on-outside-click="false" target="#icon1">Get link</v-dx-tool-tip>
            <i
                id="icon2"
                class="dx-icon-copy icon-cursor"
                @click="copyReferralLink"
                readonly
                @mouseenter="toggleDefault2"
                @mouseleave="toggleDefault2"
            />
            <v-dx-tool-tip :visible="defaultVisible2" :hide-on-outside-click="false" target="#icon2">Copy to clipboard</v-dx-tool-tip>
        </template>
    ...
</div>
```

```
import { DxTooltip } from 'devextreme-vue/tooltip';

@Component({
    components: {
        'v-dx-tool-tip': DxTooltip,
    },
})
export default class ExtendedDetailAccountComponent extends mixins(CurrentUserMixin) {
    ...
    defaultVisible1 = false;
    defaultVisible2 = false;

    toggleDefault1() {
        this.defaultVisible1 = !this.defaultVisible1;
    }

    toggleDefault2() {
        this.defaultVisible2 = !this.defaultVisible2;
    }

    async getReferralLink() {
        //
    }

    copyReferralLink() {
        //
    }
    ...
}
```

I've tried to do as following that doesn't work:

```
<div>
    ...
        <template #icon>
            <v-icon-tooltip :id="icon1" class="dx-icon-refresh icon-cursor" tooltipText="Get link" @click="getReferralLink" />
            <v-icon-tooltip :id="icon2" class="dx-icon-copy icon-cursor" tooltipText="Copy to clipboard" @click="copyReferralLink" />
        </template>
    </v-text-input>
</div>
```

```
import VIconTooltip from './v-icon-tooltip.vue';

@Component({
    components: {
        VIconTooltip,
    },
})
export default class ExtendedDetailAccountComponent extends mixins(CurrentUserMixin) {
    ...
    async getReferralLink() {
        //
    }

    copyReferralLink() {
        //
    }
    ...
}
```

**v-icon-tooltip.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <i :id="id" v-bind="$attrs" readonly @mouseenter="toggle" @mouseleave="toggle" v-on="$listeners" />
        <DxTooltip :visible="visible" :hide-on-outside-click="false" target="id">{{ tooltipText }}</DxTooltip>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { DxTooltip } from 'devextreme-vue/tooltip';

export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    components: {
        DxTooltip,
    },
    props: {
        id: {
            type: String
        },
        tooltipText: {
            type: String
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            visible: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle() {
            this.visible = !this.visible;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Your component is not correctly binding the targer in the DxTooptip ty this:

```
<DxTooltip :visible="visible" :hide-on-outside-click="false" :target="id">{{ tooltipText }}</DxTooltip>
```

I think will be works as well!

Comment: It doesn't help.